# How do I use the ASP.NET v5 Configuration in a Console App (Packaged)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The new configuration system in ASP.NET v6 is lovely for web apps but I'd like to do something similar for a Console app.  Unfortunately, I couldn't quite figure out how to do so.  The first part seems straightforward:

```
var config = new Configuration()
    .AddJsonFile("config.json");

var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.Configure<AppSettings>(config.GetSubKey(nameof(AppSettings)));
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out the balance of the needed code.  I think it likely that an OptionsManager needs to be invoked so the hydrated AppSettings object can be returned via the OptionManager.Options property, but how one wires things up, I don't have clue.

Needless to say, any help in this regard would be much appreciated...

Comment: Did you mean ASP.NET v5 and MVC 6?

Comment: Oops!  Thanks for the great catch!